# Seeing boss spawn text but no actual bosses in hardmode

Tags: terraria

I just entered hardmode and I have seen text for random hardmode boss spawns in the bottom left hand corner (like "This is going to be a terrible night..." for the twins). The problem is I don't ever see the boss. Is this normal or am I getting a glitch?

PC version of Terraria

Thanks!

Comment: Are you staying underground all night?

Comment: well I am on the surface and still experiencing same problem as mentioned above.

Answer (score 2):

According to the [wiki](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/The_Twins), if you don't defeat the Twins before sunrise, they disappear. So I would imagine you just didn't find them in time. (I don't believe they spawn underground, though I couldn't find a citation for that.)